# How to make dictionary of lda outputs and then save it into json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, gensim, lda

I am trying to save lda output in a dictionary, in which words and their probabilities will be keys and values and then save this dictionary in json but I don't know how to achieve this. When I simply try to save it in json it is some kind of binary format. Here is the code which I have tried so far:

```
   filename = sys.argv[1]
    lda = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=dictionary,alpha = 0.001, , passes=50,iterations=300)
    for i in range(0, lda.num_topics):
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(json.dumps('{}\n'.format('Topic #' + str(i + 1) + ': ')))
            for word, prob in lda.show_topic(i, topn=10):
                outfile.write(json.dumps('{}:{}\n'.format(word,prob)))
            outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Why don't use save method? :s

Comment: Tzomas i dont want to save whole model. i want to save it in a dictionary in json

Comment: But do you have intention of used it again? It's probably that on json format take more space than in binary

Comment: i will use it again .  i saw json save data in dictionary format so i thought to use this .i can save it in pickle or json but in both cases the output is in binary format